# Is there a file hosting platform supporting custom URLs or JSON export for file details

Tags: web-hosting

I am looking for a file hosting platform that can help me customize the URLs. All the file sharing/hosting platforms I know and found are providing at best custom domain but not a custom path in the way I need.

Let's say I have a list of images under flowers folder named: "flower1", "flower2", "flower3"...
and another folder named stones with a list of images named: "stones1", "stones2", "stones3"...

I need to access these images with a custom path where I can only dynamically set the name variable. Such as: "...url/flowers/flower1".

Another option for me would be the ability to export a json file for each folder containing the access URL of each file in the folder.

I tried using web hosting platforms (basically virtual machines) where I can access via FTP and upload the files in a folder I prefer and get the necessary URL for my folders and files. While this is exactly what I need, web hosting platforms are not providing unlimited external access such as Google Drive.